# xslt: removing multiple elements with one template

Tags: xslt

I have a document in html that I am converting to xml that has four `<br/>` in a row. I only need one. What is the template to convert these 4 into 1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your template is written in a push style with a default identity transform, simply match any `br` that has a `br` in front of it and do nothing.

```
<xsl:template match="br[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::br]]"/>
```

Here is an example of a full stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::br]]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```